# Angular6 - Error only in Safari -- TypeError undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

This only happens in Safari, and I have tracked it down to what line, but everything I've tried to do to get around it does not help.

It works just fine in Chrome and Firefox.

It's this line that causes the issue

`this.preppedEvents[tmpDate.getFullYear()][tmpDate.getMonth()]`

Initially I thought that maybe it was when I explicitly set a value to the 0 index, but i'm not convinced that's the solution.

The error I receive is, "TypeError undefined is not an object"

I've tried initializing the preppedEvents object with dummy data before updating it. Nothing seems to help.

```
  public constructor(private _jKiruService: JKiruService) { }

  public resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    return this._jKiruService
      .addRequest('Calendar', 'getDisplayable').runl();
  }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-learn-calendar',
  templateUrl: './learn-calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./learn-calendar.component.scss']
})
export class LearnCalendarComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public preppedEvents = [];
  private _events = [];
  private _subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _jKiruService: JKiruService,
    private _subscriber: SubscriptionService
  ) {
    this._subscriptions = this._subscriber.getSubscriber();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._subscriptions['resolver'] = this._route.params.subscribe((res) => {
      if (res) {
        this._events = this._jKiruService.pull('calendar_event', true);
      }
    });
    this.prepEvents();
  }


  public prepEvents() {
    const currentDateObj = new Date();

    // Initial Loop
    for (let y = currentDateObj.getFullYear(); y < currentDateObj.getFullYear() + 2; y++) {
      this.preppedEvents[y] = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        this.preppedEvents[y][i] = { month: OutwardDate.decodeMonth(i), events: [] };

      }
    }


    for (const event of this._events) {

      for (const day of event.events) {

        /**
         * important to note:
         * because of 0 index of month place, we need to add 1 to the display version
         * also need to format date from 2020-02-15 to 2020,02,15 to get accurate new date object
         */

        let tmpDate = new Date(day.day.replace(/-/g, ','));

            if (typeof this.preppedEvents[tmpDate.getFullYear()][tmpDate.getMonth()] === 'undefined' || this.preppedEvents[tmpDate.getFullYear()][tmpDate.getMonth()] === 'undefined' ) {
              return;
            }

        let monthDay = (tmpDate.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + tmpDate.getDate();

        this.preppedEvents[tmpDate.getFullYear()][tmpDate.getMonth()].events.push({
          title: event.title,
          description: event.description,
          day: '' + (tmpDate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + (monthDay) + '/' + tmpDate.getFullYear(), // we only need to add the 1 here to the month because its for display purposes, otherwise its index is correct
          start_time: day.start,
          end_time: day.end,
          time_description: day.description.replace(/<br>/g, ' ')
        });
      }
    }


    for (let y = currentDateObj.getFullYear(); y < currentDateObj.getFullYear() + 2; y++) {
      for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {

        this.preppedEvents[y][i].events = qsort2(this.preppedEvents[y][i].events, ['day', 'start_time']);
      }
    }

  }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the error and where it appears

[image]

**** updated with a link ****

**Here's a stackblitz link, make sure you are in Safari so the error will reproduce**
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ya3gzk

Comment: Is this the only error message you get?

Comment: @ams Yep, and only in Safari. Everything works properly in other browsers.

Comment: are you missing some polyfills?

Comment: @ams i'm not sure TBH... here's a screenshot of my polyfills.ts file

http://prntscr.com/rdw87w
http://prntscr.com/rdw8cn

Comment: @ams these are all added by default also

https://v6.angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: So which Safari and Angular versions are you using?

Comment: @ams Angular6 and any of the last 3 versions of Safari.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209338/discussion-between-ams-and-john-david).

Comment: Same problem ! Any solution ?

Comment: @BeliliF It ended up being a JS error that only Safari engine caught. I have the updated code on my other machine, I'll get back to you whenever I can get to that computer.